# Getting value from view to HttpGet controller Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Here my view.i want to pass TempData[Id] to HttpGet controller action method Index.how can i pass this values.pleae help me.thanks in advance

```
@if (TempData["Id"] != null)
{
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "QuestionnaireController", FormMethod.Get))
{
   <p>@SixSeconds.App_GlobalResources.Frontend.DeleteQuestionnaire</p> <input type = "submit" value = "@SixSeconds.App_GlobalResources.Frontend.OK"/>
}
}

 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Index(string idQ, string idTT, string easyLoad)
    {
        Project project = _getProject(idQ);
        ViewBag.LanguageCode = project.ItemLanguage.Code;
        ViewBag.projectType = project.ProjectType.ToString();
        per ricevere un questionario
        int reportCredits = 0;
        foreach (ProjectReportOption pro in project.ProjectReportOptions)
        {
            reportCredits += pro.Display && pro.ReportType != null ? pro.ReportType.Credits : 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data as route values:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "QuestionnaireController", new { idQ = TempData["Id"] }, FormMethod.Get))
{
}
```

And you need to define the route:

```
routes.MapRoute("NameOfThisRoute",
                "QuestionnaireController/Index/{idQ}",
                 new { controller = "QuestionnaireController", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: thanks for response. i use that technique but it give null exception

Comment: it work fine when i getting these value to HttPost controller method but i want to HttpGet controller action method

Comment: I updated my answer, try passing the data as route values.

Comment: Also, bases on your GlobalResources, it seems that this form is used to delete a questionnaire ? Just wanted to say that it's not good practice to change data (delete) via GET methods. It would be much better/safer to use POST. It has several advantages: you don't have to add a special route and you can use the `AntiForgeryToken` to make it safer. But anyway, the above will work with GET, if that's what you really want.